# createHttpClient is not defined - flutter

Tags: http, flutter

I want to parse JSON through HTTP listener. I'm new to Flutter so i searched it on web and added `http: ^0.12.2` package to dependencies in YAML file and still getting the error message: `"The method 'createHttpClient' isn't defined for the type '_MyHomePageState'."`

Here my two files `main.dart` and `pubspec.yaml`. In `main.dart` `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';` looks like unused and greyed out.  Can you help me what I am missing ?

**main.dart:**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _ipAddress = 'Unknown';

  _getIPAddress() async {
    String url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip';
    var httpClient = createHttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.read(url);
    Map data = json.decode(response);
    String ip = data['origin'];

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the message was in flight,
    // we want to discard the reply rather than calling setState to update our
    // non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _ipAddress = ip;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var spacer = new SizedBox(height: 32.0);

    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            spacer,
            new Text('Your current IP address is:'),
            new Text('$_ipAddress.'),
            spacer,
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _getIPAddress,
              child: new Text('Get IP address'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**:

```
name: httpdeneme2
description: A new Flutter application.



environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  http: '^0.12.2'
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: did you run command from project root -> flutter pub get

Comment: sure, it didn't help. @NeerajAmoli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the http package like this:

> import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

and in your code, update this with the code below :

```
_getIPAddress() async {
    String url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip';
    var response = await http.read(url);
    Map data = json.decode(response);
    String ip = data['origin'];

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the message was in flight,
    // we want to discard the reply rather than calling setState to update our
    // non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _ipAddress = ip;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to import http package like this

```
 import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

then replaced your method with below code

```
 _getIPAddress() async {
    String url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip';
    var response = await http.get(url);
    Map data = json.decode(response.body);
    String ip = data['origin'];
    

    if (!mounted) return;

     setState(() {
      _ipAddress = ip;
   });
}
```